# MFC (C++) CDialog DoModal() not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I have a plugin that is loaded by this application.. This plugin calls some dialog boxes with DoModal().

I'm expecting these dialog boxes to function like this: If I click on the application window behind the dialog box, the dialog box flashes and does not allow the application to be in focus.

However, in one of the other dialog boxes, called with DoModal(), if I click on the application window, it doesn't do the flashing thing, and after a while the application's close/minimize buttons become active (well, just the color). They're not really active and the window turns somewhat white and the title bar says (Not Responding)... What could possibly be wrong and how do I fix it? I've tried setting the dialog box's properties to System Modal: True, and Set Foreground: True but it doesn't seem to work.. :(

Thanks..

EDIT: I'd like to note that the in the Windows taskbar, there is only one entry for the application for the correct behavior, but when the dialog box with the incorrect behavior is launched, another "window" is launched.. So it looks like (Application)(Dialog box title).. The effect I'm trying to achieve is just (Application)..

EDIT2: The dialog box is indeed still working, even with the main app UI locked.. This dialog box also spawns another dialog box with DoModal(), and when it does, another entry is added to the taskbar, i.e. (Application)(Dialog Box1)(Dialog Box2). I am able to move Dialog Box2 around and click on Dialog Box1 and mess with it and nothing is locking.. Just that main app.. However I would like it if Dialog Box2 didn't allow Dialog Box1 to be manipulated if Dialog Box2 was open..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous poster had it right (although he deleted his answer).. I moved the function that spawned the dialog boxes to run in the application's thread and it worked..

However, is there a way to do this from another thread? By designating the parent window perhaps?

Thanks..